# Agora.io - is it possible to modify the video chat in real time

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, videochat, video-editing

I'm using Agora.io in Unity for video chat, is it possible to edit the video chat in real time in Agora.io Example: send a heart to the friend which you are having video chat. As I know Agora use the VideoSurface component to broadcast the camera texture in real time (please correct me if i'm wrong, i'm new to agora), I don't know if it's possible to edit the texture create by VideoSurface

Answer (score 0):

The VideoSurface component is rendering the received video data for you.  It does not broadcast anything.  The SDK engine encodes and transmits the video for you to remote endpoints.

Will you please clarify on "edit the texture"? Did you mean changing size or replacing the contents of the rendering texture?  In both cases the answer is yes.  You may update the transform of the texture game object for sizing.  And you may call SetForUser() to assign a different user to render on that hosting texture.

Comment: What I mean is modify the content of the texture received texture in real time,  like distord, transform, or add additional image on the texture. I kind of understand what you mean, will test it, thanks